# ViewModel accessibility in KnockOutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Why viewModel.availableCountries() is not accessible in alert message? What goes wrong in this code?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Select the car: 
    <select ></select>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         alert('The length of the array is ' + viewModel.availableCountries().length);
      </script>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var viewModel = {
                availableCountries: ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']),
                chosenCountries: ko.observableArray(['Germany']) // Initially, only Germany is selected
            };
            viewModel.chosenCountries.push('France');
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        </script>
    </form>
```

Comment: Because your `alert()` snippet is running before the `viewModel` is even created, let alone bound...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @haim770 already said, the order of your code is wrong. You are accessing the viewModel before you've created it.

Change it to the following and it should work just fine:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Select the car: 
    <select ></select>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var viewModel = {
                availableCountries: ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']),
                chosenCountries: ko.observableArray(['Germany']) // Initially, only Germany is selected
            };
            viewModel.chosenCountries.push('France');
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
            alert('The length of the array is ' + viewModel.availableCountries().length); // Moved this line down
        </script>
    </form>
```